# como passar muitas variáveis do controller para a view no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Quero passar estas variáveis, mas parece que a quantidade me impede, tem outro jeito?

```
        return view('pontuacao')->with('somas', $somas[0]->p)->with('somas1', $somas1[0]->s)->with('palpites', $palpites)->with('confrontos', $confrontos)->with('ranking', $ranking)->with('somas2', $somas2[0]->s)->with('somas3', $somas3[0]->s)->with('somas4', $somas4[0]->s)->with('somas5', $somas5[0]->s)->with('somas6', $somas6[0]->s);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colocar todos os dados em 1 array e retornar o array:

**$dados = array(
    'somas'  => $somas[0]->p,
    'somas1'   => $somas1[0]->s,
    '...' => '...'
);
return view('pontuacao')->with('dados', $dados);**

ou, passa variável por variável fora do *with()*:

**return view('pontuacao',['somas'  => $somas[0]->p, 'somas1'   => $somas1[0]->s, '...' => '...']);**

testa ai e retorna o que escolheu! :D

Salve do **ZoyO**!